# VS Code's flake8's ignore arguments don't work on format on save?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flake8

Here is my settings.json:

```json
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/zhaodachuan/anaconda3/envs/ranking_engine/bin/python",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "/mnt/c/Users/hnjyz/OneDrive/jupyter_lab/code/ranking_engine",
    ],
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=120",
        "--ignore=E402,F401",
    ],
}
```

But the `flake8` `--ignore` doesn't work when I turn on the `format on save` in VS Code.

What should I do?

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean -- flake8 isn't a formatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flake8 is not a formatter, **it's a linter**.

It's certainly [one of the supported linters of VS Code's Python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_specific-linters), but it will not affect the setting `editor.formatOnSave` or be triggered by the **Format Document** command. If configured correctly, it should automatically run and check your file for possible issues, then display them on the Problems tab:

[image: sample Flake8]

If I add:

```
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--ignore=F401"
    ],
```

Then the previously displayed F401 error should disappear:

[image: sample Flake8 with ignore]

What you seem to be looking for is a **formatter**. See the **Formatting** section of the VS Code docs on Python: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting:

> Formatting makes code easier to read by human beings by applying
> specific rules and conventions for line spacing, indents, spacing
> around operators, and so on (see an example on the [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) page).
> Formatting doesn't affect the functionality of the code itself.
> ([Linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting), on the other hand, analyzes code for common syntactical,
> stylistic, and functional errors as well as unconventional programming
> practices that can lead to errors. Although there is a little overlap
> between formatting and linting, the two capabilities are
> complementary.)
>
> The Python extension supports source code formatting using either
> [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) (the default), [black](https://github.com/python/black), or [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf).

Install one of the selected formatters, and enable `formatOnSave`:

```
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
    "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/usr/local/bin/yapf",
    "python.formatting.yapfArgs": [
        "--style=/path/to/setup.cfg"
    ],
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks . I use ```blank``` in vscode now .